# Preloader for a Wordpress Site

Tags: javascript, performance

If i want to add a pre-loader to a Wordpress site that is going to have a high image content, is it best to put the code in the head of the site?

I have done a child theme on my localhost site, but can't seem to see where is the best place to put the hmtl / javascript.  I'm not too fussed about the CSS because the link to this is in the  of the site anyway so i can place the CSS in the style.css file of my child theme.

If I put the JS in my child theme's JS file, it's not going to work properly though, because the site will have to be parsed for this to kick in?

Any help will be wonderful

Thanks

Emily,

Answer (score 1):

You will want to put the code in the child theme, otherwise an update to the parent theme will erase it.

You want the loader to be a part of the page as the document is first loaded by the browser, then use javascript to detect when the images are finished loading and remove the loader.

Check out these resources that have more information specifically on the structure of the HTML and javascript

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/display-loading-graphic-until-page-fully-loaded/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072759/display-a-loading-bar-before-the-entire-page-is-loaded

http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/

Comment: Thanks for those links Miles.  Because there are also some animations on the page, the problem with having the pre-loader as part of the document is the animations aren't linked to the load event and sometimes start before the overlay disappears.  If i was to put it in the <head> of my child theme it would become part of the normal load flow of the entire site and just be there instead of the white screen etc of a page loading?

Answer (score 0):

Add below CSS in your CSS file.

```
/** Body Overlay **/
body #load {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9901;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    transition: all .35s ease-out;
}
body #load.loader-removed {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.spinner-loader .load-wrap {
    background-image: url("images/loader.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Add below code just after the opening  tag in your website.

```
<div id="load" class="spinner-loader"><div class="load-wrap"></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Javascript function to display loader on page load
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var $load = document.getElementById("load");
        var removeLoading = setTimeout(function() {
            $load.className += " loader-removed";
        }, 500);
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps..!!